# Descrambling/dewhitening in GNURadio

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, rtl-sdr, dsp

I am currently working on project which utilizes RTL-SDR for capturing packets. I know that those packets are whitened with x^9 + x^5 + 1 polynomial. No matter what I do the descrambling each time does nothing. Packets have 20 samples per bit. I have been trying to move the average of samples, decimate/remove the 19 out of 20 samples, change seed and the endianess but to no effect. Those are the blocks I am using:
[image: blocks]
And this is the result:
[image: packets]

Comment: you will definitely need to be clock-rate-synchronized and at one symbol per value before you can apply your descrambler; but you have no clock sink!

Comment: Do you mean by clock sink, a "clock recovery MM" block? I have also tried this way but no matter the parameters I get flat zero at the output. I set Omega to 40, gain omega to 10m, mu to 0, gain mu 100m, and relative limit to 10m. I based them on this tutorial: https://nccgroup.github.io/RFTM/fsk_receiver.html. Additionally I proceeded this block with moving average block as suggested here: https://blog.habets.se/2017/04/Decoding-FSK.html

Comment: try the official GNU Radio tutorials on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org first. Both tutorials you cite are very old, from a time before we had better symbol sync in GNU Radio. The one from Thomas Habets is pretty nice, though!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I took a look at those tutorials but none seems to be addressing the task I am faceing. The closest one I guess is in the packet communication tutorial where symbol sync is used. I used it to some success to "delete" samples from bits which left me with more/less one sample per bit but this solutions seems to be more of workaround rather than solid solution. More over I have a problem with gnuradio documentation. Which is the amount of unfinished business. Many times there are "TO DO" labels on links forwarding to further explanations which is a pain

Comment: @Artur consider the WIP of documentation for an open-source project to be an opportunity for you to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I lacked was simply a "Clock Recovery MM" block with Omega set at half of number of samples per bit and the rest of parameters set to default. [image: solution]

Now the data saved in file sinks can be easily accessed with xxd command or another binary reader.